# Gtk+: print a float value to an entry widget

Tags: c, pointers, callback, gtk, type-conversion

I am despreatly trying to print a float value to an entry widget.
In principle I want to give out the value set by a scale widget at an entry widget.
I packed this functionality into a callback function which is called when the value of the scale widget is changed.

```
    static void scale_callback(GtkWidget *widget, para* para)
    {
        char text;

        para->value=gtk_range_get_value(GTK_RANGE(widget));
        text=para->value;
        printf("%c\n",text);
        gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(para->entry),&text);
    }
```

para is a structure wich holds the pointers to the entry widget, scale widget and the value (float) set by the scale widget.

```
    struct para
     {
        GtkWidget *scale;
        GtkWidget *entry;
        float value;
     };
```

My problem now is that just some random looking signs(e@A) are printed and not the correct value. I am pretty sure the mistake happens while converting the float value to the char pointer needed by the gtk_entry_set_text-function, but I don't know how to do it otherwise.
Any suggestions are welcomed (:

SOLVED:
Thanks to "some programmer dude" 's hint to snprintf it worked just by passing the buffer to gtk_entry_set_text();

Comment: What is `para->value`? Is it a single character? Maybe you want a *string* (i.e. an *array* of `char`) instead of a single character? (And of course use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to "print" into the string)

Comment: para is  a struct which holds the pointers to the entry and scale widget and a float variable (value).
All I want is to give out a float value on the entry widget

Comment: And the compiler didn't warn you about assigning a floating point value to a `char` variable? That should have given you the *first* hint that there was something wrong. The second problem is that strings are zero-terminated arrays of characters, which your variable `text` is not.

Comment: No the program compiled without warnings but when I change the value of the scale widget some random signs are printed at the entry widget

Comment: `text=para->value;
        printf("%c\n",text);` --> `printf("%e\n",para->value);`

Comment: I didn't want to print it out on the console but on an entry widget

Comment: That's why I provided you with a link to [a `snprintf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) in my first comment. And telling you about strings being *arrays* of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`g_strdup_printf`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf) instead of snprintf. With snprintf you need to know the size of resulting string, or need to use overly big buffers just to be sure you'll have all the input, or have your text truncated.

`g_strdup_printf` allocates exactly the memory needed to store the information. Just use the result and free it with `g_free` afterwards.